# Jupyter Notebook does not show any folder

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I am working on Ubuntu. I installed notebook 6.0.3 using conda. When I enter `jupyter notebook` in the terminal, the notebook dashboard won't show any files or folders. Though I can upload the files or folders, I am not able to create new folders/notebooks either. Here is the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

This is the output from the terminal for the command jupyter notebook.

```
[I 18:21:41.305 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/vkmanojk/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 18:21:41.305 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/vkmanojk/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 18:21:41.627 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/vkmanojk
[I 18:21:41.627 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 18:21:41.627 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=03ce7b30dfd1108a91c64d29a301a391c3c92192b3061d2c
[I 18:21:41.627 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=03ce7b30dfd1108a91c64d29a301a391c3c92192b3061d2c
[I 18:21:41.627 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 18:21:41.648 NotebookApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/vkmanojk/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-7821-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=03ce7b30dfd1108a91c64d29a301a391c3c92192b3061d2c
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=03ce7b30dfd1108a91c64d29a301a391c3c92192b3061d2c
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you did not run the `jupyter notebook` command from an empty folder? Note that Jupyter will only allow you to navigate the directory it was opened and its descendants, not its parents.

Comment: Yes, I ran the jupyter notebook from the home directory. It is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

you probably updated Jupyter Notebook. The notebook is no longer opened directly with a URL, but instead through a local .html file that redirects to the URL. That way, the URL with the token doesn't show in the process information anymore.

Try setting the NotebookApp.browser configuration property, or the BROWSER environment variable:
https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html

"Specify what command to use to invoke a web browser when opening the notebook. If not specified, the default browser will be determined by the webbrowser standard library module, which allows setting of the BROWSER environment variable to override it."

Comment: Yes, I did update the notebook. I am sorry but I do not know how to go with the configurations. It would be really appreciable if you can help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

just check that your browser blocks all cookies .. go to settings and enable allow all cookies and try again by typing in the command prompt